# ListSelectionListener does not fire events when calling setSelected methods

Tags: java, swing, model-view-controller, listener, propertychangelistener

First question here, hopefully I do this correctly.

Below is a minimal example of my problem that I quickly whipped up representative of my project. I have created a custom renderer for a JList containing some objects (in the example I've used Strings for illustrative purposes). My issue is that, as far as I can tell, if I add a `ListSelectionListener` to the list, the family of `setSelected...()` methods do not fire events that trigger the conditional `if(e.getValueIsAdjusting())`.

In the example below, the problem is immediately obvious upon starting the program: even though `list.setSelectedIndex(2);` is called after assigning the JLabel's selected text as "none", it does not change until you, the user, click the list items. In fact, it must be a different item to the one currently selected.

I would like this functionality so that the flow of my program will be that, after a user adds/removes items from the list, the "view" is immediately updated once the selected list item is changed.

Have I done something wrong, or am I approaching this incorrectly?

Thank you. :)

```java
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.beans.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Example implements PropertyChangeListener {
    String ITEM_SELECTED = "Item Selected";
    String DELETE_SELECTED = "Delete Selected";
    PropertyChangeSupport pcs = new PropertyChangeSupport(this);
    JLabel selected;

    JList<String> list;
    DefaultListModel<String> model;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Example();
    }

    public Example() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

        model = new DefaultListModel<>();
        model.addElement("Entry 1");
        model.addElement("Entry 2");
        model.addElement("Entry 3");
        model.addElement("Entry 4");
        model.addElement("Entry 5");

        list = new JList<>(model);

        selected = new JLabel("Currently selected: none");
        list.setSelectedIndex(2);

        list.addListSelectionListener(e -> {
                if(e.getValueIsAdjusting()) {
                    pcs.firePropertyChange(ITEM_SELECTED, null, null);
                }
            }
        );

        JButton removeItem = new JButton("Remove item");

        removeItem.addActionListener(e -> {
                pcs.firePropertyChange(DELETE_SELECTED, null, null);
            }
        );

        mainPanel.add(new JScrollPane(list), BorderLayout.WEST);
        mainPanel.add(removeItem, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        mainPanel.add(selected, BorderLayout.CENTER);       

        pcs.addPropertyChangeListener(this);

        frame.add(mainPanel);
        frame.setSize(300, 400);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
        String event = (String) evt.getPropertyName();

        if (event.equals(ITEM_SELECTED)) {
            selected.setText("Currently selected: " + list.getSelectedValue());
        }

        if (event.equals(DELETE_SELECTED)) {
            int selectedIndex = list.getSelectedIndex();
            model.removeElement(list.getSelectedValue());

            if (selectedIndex > 0)
                list.setSelectedIndex(selectedIndex-1);
            else if (selectedIndex == 0)
                list.setSelectedIndex(selectedIndex);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: *am I approaching this incorrectly?* - not sure what you are really attempting to do. I don't understand the need for the PropertyChangeListener. You already handle the selection change event in the ListSelectionListener, why add another level of indirection. Just add the processing logic currently in the PropertyChangeListener to the ListSelectionListener. Same for the "remove" logic. You already have an ActionListener, why involve the PropertyChangeListener?

Comment: Read the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Lists](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html) for a working example of dynamically adding/removing items for a JList.

Comment: The inclusion of a property change listener was so that the given example mimicked my project. There, everything is designed to be modular and follow MVC, so this example would've actually been written with at least 2 separate classes. I wrote everything here to be in one class so that it was easy to copy-paste and test. I understand the redundancy. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `e.getValueIsAdjusting()` method checks if the value is still being adjusted. In your case it looks like the event fired by `list.setSelectedIndex(2)` would have `e.getValueIsAdjusting()` return false.

You can probably fix this by doing the opposite check : `!e.getValueIsAdjusting()`.

This will then check that any change responded to is the final one for that chain of events.

Comment: Yep, that did it. On the downside, fixing this has introduced so many new bugs that I need to fix, but such is programming, I guess. Thank you!

Comment: @TomH Not sure how that completely solved the problem. The code you posted hasn't even added the ListSelectionListener to the JList and the PropertyChangeListener hasn't been  added to the PropertyChangeSupport, so those events would not be generated when the index is set to 2.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. The JList and button have listeners added to them as lambdas and the class itself implements PropertyChangeListener and was added to the PCS object near the end (`pcs.addPropertyChangeListener(this);`). I do realise that I added a redundant method at the end, though (con of trying to minimally reproduce my project). I just got rid of it.

Comment: You are correct, though, that adding the negation did not fix the initial index being displayed in the JLabel, but it did fix the problem where deleting an item and reselecting another didn't change the label. For my purposes the latter was enough to allow me to continue with my project, but if you have suggestions to have the initial selection fire an event too I'm all ears. :)

Comment: *I'm not sure what you mean* - look at the logical order of your code 1) set the index 2) add the selection listener 3) add the proper change listener. How can setting the index generate an event if the listeners haven't even be added yet?

Comment: To get it to fire you only need to move the line list.setSelectedIndex(2); lower down. In terms of following good practices for swing, make sure you do all this initialisation on the event queue with EventQueue.invokeLater(Runnable). You might already be doing this in your full project.